# How to partition memory of NFC tag(classic)?

Tags: nfc, mifare, ndef

I am looking for a way to partition memory(8Kb) of NFC tag. Because while writing a large amount of data to NFC tag from NFC device, there might be the chances of data loss of NFC tag while tapping NFC tag. So will partition the memory into 2 parts. or any other solution for this?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: write a chunk of data, read back, if ok Repeat, if not Ok raise an exception ...